# Android, How to Scroll Programmatically a scrollview When I Clicked on edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview, ontouchlistener

When ı clicked on `edittext`, the users can not see my `button` because of keyboard.

So I want, When the users clicked on `edittext`, `scrollview` go to above absolutely with smooth effect.

My First Question Which listener should I use for this ?  `OnClick`, `OnFocus` , `OnTouch` etc. ?

I tried this code block, but it needs double click to scroll it. First click open the keyboard and second click scroll to `scrollview`.

My Second Question Anyone have an idea about this problem ?  Thanks for helping.

```
 scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
    et_space.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 500);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you guys for all answers, but I solved my problem by myself,

First I would like to say you have to use "OnFocusListener" and then you have to use Handler like this;

Now, When I click my edittext; keyboard opened and scrollview scrolled to top at the same time :)

```
et_space.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus){
                final Handler handler;
                handler = new Handler();

                final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 500);

                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(r, 200);
            }  
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
 use this code in OnClickListener of EditText

```
scrollview.scrollBy(0,scrollview.getBottom());
```

Comment: I wrote in my question; 
"scrollview go to above absolutely with smooth effect."

Answer (score 0):

```
sv.scrollTo(5, 10);
```

hope this will help you.

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sv.scrollTo(5, 10);
    }
});
```

Comment: I already tried this before, It needs double click too, anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this:

```
et_space.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 500);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This solution does not pop up the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can add a widget at the same place under your EditText.Such as a ImageView named "btn_show_keyboard".

Then execute this mothod in your btn_show_keyboard.onClick() method.

```
public void showSoftInput() {
    mEditText.requestFocus();     
    mInputManager.showSoftInput(mEditText, 0);
}
```

Set your target Activity in this softinputmode.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Try these,hope it helps.